# PRAUC curve Interpretation on imbalanced data

Tags: unbalanced-classes, auc, precision-recall

My training data is undersampled to a positive to negative ratio of 5%. I observe a PRAUC of .4 on my training data. When I test the model on real-world data where the positive to negative ratio is .5%, the PRAUC drops to .125. In this case, how do I interpret the drop in PRAUC. I understand that the PRAUC has a baseline of positive to negative of that dataset and the drop may not be as bad as it looks. Can someone help me understand this drop in PRAUC? I am particularly interested in knowing if the model is still predicting the positive cases as positive in the test dataset as it was in the training dataset.

Comment: Why do you under/oversample the data at hand, to begin with? To that extent, even if we undersampled the *training* data, we should not do that to our *test* set. Assuming you do a  five-fold CV, the under/oversampling happens in each training fold independently, such that the validation fold prevelance is unchanged.